# Getting wrong timestamp in Java REST web services from AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, web-services, rest

I wrote an application in angularJS and REST web services.
AngularJS will hit a REST web services and gets the date. When I did console.log in angularJS it displayed as below.

```
date_modified: "2016-03-18T10:44:43"
```

Now I send back the data to REST web services, and in Java i made a sysout of Date Object and its coming as below.

```
Fri Mar 18 16:14:43 IST 2016
```

Here Date is coming fine, but the time is wrong. **In angularJS its 10:44:43** and **in Java its 16:14:43**.

I want the correct time in Java REST web services. The data type used in Java is util.date

Pls help get through this issue.

Answer (score -1):

You need to take care of server and client timezone. The time that you are getting is most likely getting converted to GMT.

I would suggest using:
1. `joda-time` [library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) if you are using JDK 7 or less
2. JDK 8 Date time library

Comment: Server and client timezone are same only as it is deployed locally on tomcat server on my machine.

Comment: Yeah, but your client machine is in some timezone, which is being converted to GMT when you use util.Date. Try joda-time (org.joda.time.LocalDate or LocalDateTime if you need time) and you will be good.

Answer (score -1):

Here is problem is timezone. Your server timezone is wrong so that its return wrong time.
Please check your server timezone. OR get time according to timezone or you own your side change time to according to your timezone.

Comment: Client and server are both on my machine.The server is tomcat and is deployed locally on tomcat.

Comment: Then check your system time. Otherwise, this type of problem is not occurs when you work on local server.